# computing Histogram of oriented gradients on log polar bins

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I want to compute histogram of oriented gradient on my image. But I don't want to divide the image to regular square blocks. I'm going to divide the image to uniform log polar bins(like bins in shape context or bins like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258740/drawing-shape-context-logpolar-bins-in-matlab/) ) and then on each bin(block) the histogram of gradient with 8 orientation is computed.

But
1) I don't know how to divide the image to log polar bins. Can I use shape context? Or even the above link for partitioning to these bins?

2) how can I compute HOG on this bins since available codes(in matlab, OpenCV and EmguCV) use square bins? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds pretty much like the C-HOG (circular HOG) features in the [original HOG paper](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf). The only difference wrt typical hog is the shape of the bins. I think it would be best to:

- iterate over the pixels
- calculate the circular bin number for each pixel
- add the contribution of the gradient at the pixel to the histogram corresponding to the bin number

A good starting point would be the pseudo-matlab-code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115112/1576602

Comment: Thanks alot @Andrzej your answer is helpful to me. I'm working on it ;-)

Comment: Sorry I found that C-HOG is exactly what I want(I mean even its shape was what I want with single circular central cell) but i couldn't find any sample code for this type of HOG, do you know any sample code of this hog? I searched but found nothing.

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not aware of any existing code, but please see my advice and link I sent. I'm sure that having an implementation of standard HOG and that, you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks I'm still working on it but the progress is so slow and I'm really in hurry:-) anyway thank you And